# Event Sourcing and Clean Architecture - does domain model need to handle events?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, clean-architecture

I'm still learning clean architecture and now I'm trying to implement event sourcing in project.
I have 2 projects, one that hold commands and events and one where is domain model.
By definition of clean architecture domain model is center of everything. Everytthing references him.
But, all examples that I found shows that domain model have `Apply`  methods for each event.

Do I need to do this in domain model? Or is some other way?

In some point in code I need to reconstruct domain model from events something like this:

```
public void Load(events){
foreach(var event in events)
{
   Apply(event);
}}
```

This should be in domain model class, like `Apply` method.
Apply method changes internal state of domain model.

Comment: Could you provide some samples of code just to make it little easier for us to imagine? Cheers

Comment: This is quite broad. Obviously, there are thousands of ways of doing anything in programming. You're apparently reading a book or learning from some source and assuming we all know what you're talking about. Please [edit] you question to provide more context to your question.

Comment: _"But, all examples that I found shows that domain model have Apply methods for each event."_ - why is there a "but"? How else would you apply changes to your model of the domain?

Comment: @Fildor like I sad, still learning, dont know. Because of that I've posted question

Comment: Ah, ok. I think the example actually helped understand your misconception. See the (domain) model is supposed to hold the _current_ state of the domain. If you start the system, it has no state or a blank state, if you will. So you need to warm it up by giving it a seed and then perform all historic changes to that state up until you have the current state.

Comment: @Fildor I think I understand. So It is okay to have those Apply methods in domain model?

Comment: @milandjukic88 It is not only "ok", but you _need_ to have those. Otherwise you couldn't perform a thing that's called "replay".

Comment: @Fildor understand now. Thank you so much. I have just one question. I saw that many examples have list of events directly in domain model. Is it okay to store those event in event store and then, when needed, to restore domain object from events in event store?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239081/discussion-between-milandjukic88-and-fildor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all examples that I found shows that domain model have Apply methods for each event.
> Do I need to do this in domain model?

You don't "have to" do that, but it is a likely outcome in a Kingdom of Nouns design.  Since much of the early development of domain driven design (Java) and event sourcing (C#) were taking place in the Kingdom of Nouns, the examples tend to share these patterns.

With the `Apply` pattern, you are seeing the result of two different ideas.

One, the idea that all event sourced models have the same underlying data structure (Truth is the history of events), so we should be using a single common, general purpose implementation for all of them.

Two, that the information we cache within the data model (aka the model object's "properties") should look "the same" whether we are looking at the original object that processed the command or if we are instead looking at a copy of that model loaded from the history.

Thus, a pattern emerged that models tend to "inherit" from some base class that owns an event history and an api for coordinating changes to both the history and the models own internal cache, and that command handlers on the model work by first calculating what changes (events) should happen, then *applying* those changes using the same code paths that would be used when reloading the event history.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the Kingdom of Verbs (aka "functional programming"), an event is nothing more than a function mapping a state (alt. "model object") to a state/"model object"; the ubiquitous language of that Kingdom would likely refer to "applying an event to a state" (thanks to the history of Lisp/Scheme if nothing else).

Comment: There's also a not-facially-absurd argument that a large portion of DDD/ES and related practices is just smuggling functional programming into "the enterprise"...